# How to manually upload ringtones and notifications to DroidX?

Tags: notifications, motorola-droid-x, ringtone

I've created 2 folders on the root of the SD card,

- Ringtones
- Notifications

and placed one mp3 file within each. When I disconnect the DroidX from the USB cable and navigate to either "Settings" > "Sound"> "Phone ringtone", or "Settings" > "Sound" > "Notification ringtone", neither mp3 file shows up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make your own folders.

The proper file to put the mp3s is /system/media/audio/ - where you will find folders for /alarms , /notifications , and /ringtones

There are two things to keep in mind when doing this:

1. If you are using full-sized .mp3's , you will put considerable strain on the system when it comes time to load one. In my experience, two minutes of mp3 works fine for an alarm, but such a file takes a few seconds to load, and will not make for a suitable ringtone, unless you trim the file first.
2. You will have to re-do this every time you flash a new ROM.

An alternative to this -- is to have them in /sdcard/media/ -- 
But if you have an older device, having them in the root directory allows for better performance.

HTH!

Comment: Root directory? What root directory? Your method needs root and according to the Android developer documentation his directories are correct. What's "full-sized mp3" and why does it put a strain on the device. BTW I've never encountered any performance issue with MP3 ringtones.

Comment: I can't find the "system" folder on the root

Comment: @mre rm-vanda refers to a folder which is only accessible if you have a rooted device. That folder is usually mounted read-only, so (without root) you cannot write there. To keep your own ringtones etc. even after ROM-updates, this method is rather discouraged. Instead, rather check [Is there any documentation on the correct/expected directory structure of the external memory card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5875/is-there-any-documentation-on-the-correct-expected-directory-structure-of-the-ex/28071#28071).

Comment: Ah, yes, when you said "root of the device" - I didn't realize you meant the root of the sdcard. 

In that case, go for /sdcard/media/notifications and /sdcard/media/ringtones

Comment: @RichardBorcsik 
Try putting a 4 minute mp3 as a ringtone on your /sdcard/ 

Call your phone. See how long it takes for it to ring. 

=)

Comment: @rm-vanda It rings without any noticeable delay. I don't think that it reads the entire file. That's unnecessary.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik - okay, okay- 
I was recalling my days with a G1 for that one.

Comment: I think now `/system` is read-only, so youo must use `/sdcard`. But that isn't working for me either on 5.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

You probably found the correct location (if your "root of the device" refers to the root of your sdcard). For details on those directories, please check with [Is there any documentation on the correct/expected directory structure of the external memory card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5875/is-there-any-documentation-on-the-correct-expected-directory-structure-of-the-ex/28071#28071).

One thing which however may apply: For those files to become available with your settings, the *Media Scanner* must have been run and having them indexed. Usually this should happen automatically when your SD-card gets mounted; but it may be much delayed when you did not unmount/remount the card (and e.g. copied files directly on the device). In those cases, a little app like [SDrescan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bero.sdrescan), [Scan Media](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dcd.scanmedia), or [SDSync (SD Card Update)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SdSync) might prove useful.